# Can we use source database endpoints which are hosted on other servers than AWS server for using AWS DMS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms

Can we use source database endpoints which are hosted on other servers than AWS server for using AWS DMS? If yes, can you help me by sharing any tutorials.
I have seen [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBPFr.jpg) in AWS official documentation.
Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use DMS to migrate an on-prem (or diff cloud) db to AWS and vice versa.
In same documentation from where you take snapshot for e.g you have part "Migrating an On-Premises Oracle Database to Amazon Aurora MySQL".
If you check your screenshoot you can notice "The source **or** target database must be on an AWS service"

You have a very nice explanation in this blog article:
https://medium.com/workfall/how-to-do-database-migration-using-aws-database-migration-service-dms-from-on-premise-ec2-to-rds-d46b9144d3cc